# How to get detailed test info from PHPUnit testdox

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

When generating a log file using testdox-html the results shown are simply the names of the test methods that are either strike through text if fail or normal if passed. What I'd like is for the testdox file to generate the error information much like the command line output. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 9):

The Code that creates the HTML is located in `PHPUnit/Util/TestDox/ResultPrinter/HTML.php` and sadly I don't know any way to extend it. You can just change it, but then you'd have to repeat that for every update which could get annoying.

Since the output is rather small anyway, I'd go another path:

I'd use the .xml file phpunit output (e.g. `phpunit --log-junit foo.xml DemoTest.php` ) and use xslt or a dom parser to transform the output into html. It shouldn't be much work and you can customize it very quickly.

I've written a little example using `xslt` to transform the output.

### Test

```
<?php

class DemoTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testPass() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

    public function testFail() {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
    }

}
```

### Create xml output

`phpunit --log-junit foo.xml DemoTest.php`

### The xslt template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h1>Tests</h1>
      <xsl:for-each select="testsuites/testsuite">
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></h2>
        <ul>
        <xsl:for-each select="testcase">
          <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
            <xsl:if test="failure">
                <b>Failed !</b>
                <i><xsl:value-of select="*"/></i>
            </xsl:if>
          </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Transforming the output

`xsltproc foo.xsl foo.xml > output.html`

### What it looks like

```
<html>
<body>
  <h1>Tests</h1>
    <h2>DemoTest</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>testPass</li>
        <li>testFail<b>Failed !</b>
          <i>DemoTest::testFail
          Failed asserting that &lt;boolean:false&gt; is true.
          /home/edo/DemoTest.php:10
          </i>
       </li>
      </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

and it should be easily adapted because you can use all the values in the xml file like the runtime of each tests and so on.

### Alternatives

You could use a DomParser, just modify the PHPUnit class or maybe someone else has a quicker idea :)

Comment: Be careful, as shown in [the documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/other-uses-for-tests.html), the test case name can be changed if you use numeric suffixes: "If there are several test methods whose names only differ in a suffix of one or more digits, such as testBalanceCannotBecomeNegative() and testBalanceCannotBecomeNegative2(), the sentence "Balance cannot become negative" will appear only once, assuming that all of these tests succeed."